# Can't add new field in the django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, makemigrations

> Django 2.0

I've created a model in `Blog app`,

```
class Category(models.Model):
    field1 = models....
    field2 = models....
    field3 = models....
```

and after some time I want to add a new field in that model.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    field1 = models....
    cover_pic = .models....
    field2 = models....
    field3 = models....
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273950/5132337) answer. But it gives me the following error.

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'blog_category.cover_pic' in 'field list'")`

Answer (score 4):

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273950/5132337) answer is from 2014 and for an old Django version.

The workflow for adding new fields is simple:

1. Write code for the field in your model.
2. Run command `manage.py makemigrations`.
3. Run command `manage.py migrate`.

This is all in the documentation.

---

Since, you already followed [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273950/5132337) answer and have run the `manage.py --fake` command, you have messed up your db state a little bit.

To recover, do this:

1. Go to your "blog" app's "migration" folder.
2. Look at the names of the migration files. They should look like `0001_category_field1.py, 0002_category_cover_pic.py`.
3. The faked migration will be the one with name something like `0002_category_cover_pic.py`. Note its number, like `0002`.
4. Now you'll have to move back to the previously applied migration. So, if the faked migration number is `0002`, the previously applied migration will be `0001`.
5. Now run this command - `manage.py migrate --fake myapp 0001`. Note the number of the migration file. You'll have to fake another migration back to the previously applied migration file.
6. Now run command - `manage.py migrate myapp`.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: can you give me the link of documentation for this topic. I tried but couldn't find it

Comment: BTW, my first try was that you mentioned in your answer. I simply added the field in model and ran the `makemigrations` still getting the same error.

Comment: and yet the answer is old, but it also mentioned exactly the same steps as you mentioned except first two steps which have nothing to do there and has no effect.

Comment: @DeadPool The [link to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#workflow). No, the answer is not same. It is about upgrading from an older django version to a newer django version, that's why the `--fake` parameter is used in the command. You also need to run `migrate` command to apply the newly generated migrations after `makemigrations`.

Comment: I'm getting the error in `makemigrations` phase, so it should be run well before running the `migrate` command.

Comment: Well I have some unexpected result. When I am adding a new field in my `Post` model, it is running well but when I'm doing the same in `Category` model, it is showing the error above, both belongs to the same app `Blog`

Comment: @DeadPool You might have messed up your migrations by running the `migrate --fake` command. This is also [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake). Wait a few minutes, I'll try to find a solution.

Comment: Ok, yeah maybe right. I here, thanks for your effort.

Comment: @DeadPool I've updated the answer with a recovery solution. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're problem is not solved yet and you don't have important data in your database, I would suggest start your database from fresh. Delete all your database tables, then delete all the migration files inside your `app_name/migration` folders. Now run the two commands and start developing.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Now you will have a fresh database and you are good to go. From next time try to follow the way mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: On the above question mentioned that the DB has been worked with three field and after a time with stored data on DB now we want add new column on it. So consider that we can't remove DB or old migrations file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a new field in the Django model and after deploying to any environment , you are getting error while accessing the field.
Error:
"1054, Unknown column"

Although i also was not able to figure out how to resolve it but i came up with a work around.

1. I created a column manually in the DB .
2. I added the same field in the model.
3. Again tried to access the field and it worked like a charm.

I hope it helps your case.